# Not getting notification/request using application request dialog box

Tags: facebook, dialog, request, apprequests

I am trying to build application request on my website using request dialog box.

When i send app request to friends, notification appears for a moment & goes away. Also it is not showing any new notifications either in "**App & games**" and "**notifications**" pages.

Here Sample Code :-

FB.init({
        appId  : '127617823933232',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        oauth: true,
      });

function sendRequestToRecipients() {

```
var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'EventSeekr Join Request',
    to: user_ids, 
}, requestCallback);
```

}

function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
         message: 'EventSeekr Join Requestt'
   }, requestCallback);

}

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question based on some issues I was having with my app, see if it helps:

From my experience and from reading the [Facebook Developer Guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), it seems like it's mandatory for you to have a Canvas defined for your Facebook app so the requests render as Notifications.

I am trying to solve a problem where these notifications show fine in the Facebook website but not on the Facebook Android client's notification popup.